# Javascript keycodes for Alt, Ctrl, and Shift

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$("#text").bind('keypress', function(e) {
    var code = (e.KeyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which);  
    alert(code);
}
```

It works fine for everything except <kbd>Alt</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>, or <kbd>Shift</kbd>.
But in all tutorials that i found it should echos 17, 18, 19

Why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use `.keydown()` or `.keyup()`

[see it in action](http://jsfiddle.net/b5BPq/)

```js
jQuery(function($){
  var output = $('.output');
  $("#text1").bind('keypress', function(e) {
    var code = (e.KeyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which);  
    output.text(code);
  });
  $("#text2").bind('keydown', function(e) {
    var code = (e.KeyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which);  
    output.text(code);
  });
  $("#text3").bind('keyup', function(e) {
    var code = (e.KeyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which);  
    output.text(code);
  });
  
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
keypress <input type="text" id="text1"> <br>
keydown <input type="text" id="text2"> <br>
keyup <input type="text" id="text3">

<br><br>
Output: <span class="output"></span>
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered using the jquery.hotkeys extension that allows you to bind by specifying a string?

```
"C-A-q" would bind you to:
```

<kbd>Control</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>q</kbd>.

Comment: the OP did not mention about any combination keys :)

Comment: Considering what his code is (probably) going to be used for, it is a viable alternative. :P

Answer (score 1):

It would probably be better to use console.log to find them. You can also use just one textbox easily for this.

```
$("#textbox").keydown(function(e) {
    console.log("keydown: "+e.keyCode);
});
```

And do the same for keyup and keypress to see better how it all works.

Side note: JavaScript sure is hard to write on a phone ;)