# Problem capturing keycode

Tags: jquery

```
 $(document).bind('keypress', function(e) {
 var code = (e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which);
 alert(code)
 });
```

The above code is not returning anything if i click alt,start,prtscrcn etc..
Please someone help me..

Comment: POssible dup of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3580985/javascript-keycodes-for-alt-ctrl-shift

Comment: There is nothing wrong with your code.

Answer (score 3):

Did you read the [jQuery doco on keypress](http://api.jquery.com/keypress/)?

`keypress` doesn't get triggered by "modifier" keys like shift, alt, etc. Use `keyup` or `keydown` instead.

Note that alt tends to activate the browser's menu, so subsequent keypresses may not register in your web page.

There are several [web site](http://javascript.info/tutorial/keyboard-events)s where you can try out the differences between `keypress`, `keyup` and `keydown`.

Answer (score 0):

Works fine for me: [Examples](http://jsfiddle.net/Xqk5T/) (Click in the result box, then type)

<strike>I think you just missed a semicolon.</strike>

Comment: If you mean the "missed" semicolon after `alert(code)`, remember that semicolons are (mostly) optional in JS.

Comment: Everything works fine BUT alt, option, etc. Thats the problem Reddy is having

Comment: Alt triggers a browser reaction, not something in the webpage.